# Response received from web service is null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, ksoap2

I am sending details to be stored in a database using a web service using KSOAP. I have used visual studio to create the web service. The web service works fine. A string will be returned when the details have been inserted into the database. The problem is that this string is empty, maybe something is wrong in the way that i am getting the response. I have been trying to find out whats wrong for a long time. please help

```
public class Registration extends Activity{
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/register";
private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "register";
private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:58076/WebSite1/Service.asmx";
Button sqlRegister, sqlView;

EditText  sqlFirstName,sqlLastName,sqlEmail,sqlMobileNumber,sqlCurrentLocation,sqlUsername,sqlPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.registration);
sqlFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
sqlLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLname);
sqlEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
sqlMobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
sqlCurrentLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCurrentLoc);

sqlUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
sqlPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPwd);

sqlRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
sqlRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRegister:
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        break;
      }
     }
    });
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         String firstname = sqlFirstName.getText().toString();
         String lastname = sqlLastName.getText().toString();
         String emailadd = sqlEmail.getText().toString();
         String number = sqlMobileNumber.getText().toString();
         String loc = sqlCurrentLocation.getText().toString();
         String uname = sqlUsername.getText().toString();
         String pwd = sqlPassword.getText().toString();

         SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
         Request.addProperty("fname", String.valueOf(firstname));
         Request.addProperty("lname", String.valueOf(lastname));
         Request.addProperty("email", String.valueOf(emailadd));
         Request.addProperty("num", String.valueOf(number));
         Request.addProperty("loc", String.valueOf(loc));
         Request.addProperty("username", String.valueOf(uname));
         Request.addProperty("password", String.valueOf(pwd));

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
         HttpTransportSE httpTransport  = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
         Log.d("work","work");
         try
         {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
             String result =  response.getProperty(0).toString();
             Log.d("res",result);
             if(result.equals("reg"))
             {
                 Log.d("reg","reg");
                 return "Registered";
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.d("no","no");
                 return "Not Registered";
             }
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return null;

    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("tag","onpost");
        if(result!=null)
        {

            if(result.equals("Registered"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "You have been registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(result.equals("Not Registered"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Somethings wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ///This is what gets printed on screen
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    }   
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to change value of SOAP_ACTION. The `SOAP_ACTION` is `http://tempuri.org/register`. It should be `http://10.0.2.2:58076/WebSite1/Service.asmx`

Comment: Use SOAPUI tool first to see your SOAP response is coming as you desired..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your webservice is returning a `String`.
Try using this to solve your problem

```
          Object result = envelope.getResponse();
```

when your webservice return values of type byte[] ,you can do this:

```
          SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Hope it helps